# GCP Cloud Build deploying a scheduler job

Tags: yaml, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-scheduler

We have the following in our cloudbuild.yaml file and it is creating our cloud scheduler job as expected.

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ['scheduler', 'jobs', 'create', 'http', 'test-job',
            '--schedule', '30 1 * * 7',
            '--time-zone', 'Asia/Taipei',
            '--uri', 'MyURI',
            '--message-body', 'msg payload',
            '--location', 'asia-east1',
            '--oauth-service-account-email', 'service_account_name',
    ]
```

But when we trigger the cloud build again, since the job has already created, the code failed. Instead of creating, the code need to be modified manually

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ['scheduler', 'jobs', 'update', 'http', 'test-job',
            '--schedule', '30 1 * * 7',
            '--time-zone', 'Asia/Taipei',
            '--uri', 'MyURI',
            '--message-body', 'msg payload',
            '--location', 'asia-east1',
            '--oauth-service-account-email', 'service_account_name',
    ]
```

We would like to keep both of these in our cloudbuild.yaml by using if-else expression rather than manually edit the args. How would we, if possible, restructure the build steps in Build configuration file schema ([Build config file schema](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema)) that would check if the job exists, if not create. If job exists and no changes, continue. If changes are present then update.